# Can't run exec command in MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `RTList`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `INSERT_INTO_MT_Tables`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `INSERT_INTO_MT_Tables`(
IN mtTableName VARCHAR(10)
, IN mTableName VARCHAR(15)
, IN mtField VARCHAR(15)
, IN mtItemID VARCHAR(15)
, IN mtItemName VARCHAR(15)
, IN AdminID INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQLString VARCHAR(200);

SET @SQLString = 
'INSERT INTO ' + mtTableName +
'(' + mtItemID + ', ' + mtField + ', User_Created, Date_Created, User_Modified, Date_Modified)'
+ ' SELECT ' + mtItemID + ' , ' + mtField + ', AdminID, NOW(), AdminID, NOW()
FROM ' + mTableName + '
WHERE ' + mtField + ' = ''' + mtItemName + ''' LIMIT 1;';

PREPARE test FROM @SQLString;
EXECUTE test;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL INSERT_INTO_MT_Tables('MT_Phone', 'M_Phone', 'Phone_Number', 'PhoneID', '12345678', 1);
```

Here is the error message after I changed (execute cmd after end):

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXECUTE test;
DELIMITER' at line 2
```

Here is the error message after I changed (execute cmd before end):

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@SQLString VARCHAR(200);
SET @SQLString = 
'INSERT INTO ' + mtTableName +
'(' + ' at line 9
```

Hi there,

Please see above coding of mine. I have little knowledge for stored procedure.
But I tried to look around before posted this question.
Seems the cmd is simple, but still with no luck i can run this cmd.

Could you please tell me where I wrote it wrongly so that this didn't work?

really appreciate your knowledge with this basic question.

thanks.

Comment: is `mtItemName` a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended your procedure definition with `END $$` before your PREPARE and EXECUTE.  Those statements should belong inside the procedure body (before the `END$$`).

The specific reason for the error is that your PREPARE statement and EXECUTE statement are not separated by the delimiter currently in effect when you run them.

To fix both problems, just move the line with `END $$` after the PREPARE and EXECUTE.

---

Re your comment:

There are some other problems with your code.

The `+` operator does not perform string concatenation in MySQL.  (That's a behavior of Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access, and Sybase.)  In MySQL, use [`CONCAT(string1, string2, ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or else set `SQL_MODE=PIPES_AS_CONCAT` and use the `||` operator to match ANSI SQL syntax.

You can't DECLARE a `@`-prefixed [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html).  These user-defined variables are kind of like global variables scoped to the session.  You don't need to declare them, just start using them.  They accept any length string, so there's no need to declare the data type or length.

You must use this type of variable for PREPARE, not a local variable created with DECLARE.  So you don't need the DECLARE at all in this procedure.

Here's a version of your script that I tested on MySQL 5.5.30:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `INSERT_INTO_MT_Tables`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `INSERT_INTO_MT_Tables`(
IN mtTableName VARCHAR(10)
, IN mTableName VARCHAR(15)
, IN mtField VARCHAR(15)
, IN mtItemID VARCHAR(15)
, IN mtItemName VARCHAR(15)
, IN AdminID INT)
BEGIN

SET @SQLString =
CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', mtTableName,
'(', mtItemID, ', ', mtField, ', User_Created, Date_Created, User_Modified, Date_Modified)',
' SELECT ', mtItemID, ' , ', mtField, ', AdminID, NOW(), AdminID, NOW()
FROM ', mTableName, '
WHERE ', mtField, ' = ''', mtItemName, ''' LIMIT 1');

PREPARE test FROM @SQLString;
EXECUTE test;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL INSERT_INTO_MT_Tables('MT_Phone', 'M_Phone', 'Phone_Number', 'PhoneID', '12345678', 1);
```

Comment: thanks for the advise.. it still failed to run with same error code.. is there anything else that i missed?

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin .. it is working perfectly well now.. didn't realize that + sign is not working here..